# datetime range indexing: datetimes that may not be in the index?

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have a dataframe indexed by `datetime` objects:

```
In <10>: all_data.head().index
Out<10>: 
Index([2014-04-23, 2014-04-13, 2014-04-15, 2014-04-30, 2014-04-06], dtype='object')
```

and two timestamps:

```
In <11>: d1
Out<11>: datetime.datetime(2014, 3, 24, 0, 0)

In <12>: d2
Out<12>: datetime.datetime(2014, 4, 6, 0, 0)
```

I would like to index a column base don the `d1:d2` range. Note that `d1` or `d2` may **not** be in the index. How can I do this in Pandas?

I tried:

```
all_data.loc[d1:d2,:]
```

but I get: `start bound[2014-03-24 00:00:00] is not the [index]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if you make the index a `DateTimeIndex`, partial string indexing should work:

```
print df
print df.index

            x1  x2
date              
2014-04-23   1   2
2014-04-13   2   4
2014-04-15   3   6
2014-04-30   4   8
2014-04-06   5  10

[5 rows x 2 columns]

<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2014-04-23, ..., 2014-04-06]
```

Then you can use partial string slicing:

```
print df['2014-03-24':'2014-04-06']

            x1  x2
2014-04-06   5  10
```

or

```
print df.ix['2014-03-24':'2014-04-13',:]

            x1  x2
date              
2014-04-13   2   4
2014-04-06   5  10
```

Comment: Thanks -- How do I convert my current index to `DateTimeIndex` ?

Comment: try: `df.index = df.index.to_datetime()` (not to_pydatetime)

Comment: Thanks. I actually have two indices (one is `datetime`, the other one is a string). Is `to_datetime()` an `Index` method?? If so, how can I apply it to only one of the index levels?

Comment: No, see here for the non-index version: [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html)

Comment: Thanks. When you mentioned `"partial string indexing"` what is that exactly? Is pandas smart enough to create date ranges when using dates in string format and only retrieve the ones included in the index? If so, why does it support date ranges in string format and not in datetime format? It's a bit odd.

Comment: See here: [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#partial-string-indexing). pandas supports both but I think datetime indexing has to be exact to work. Partial string indexing doesn't (I think that is why the call it partial string indexing).